# How to make a photo frame over an image in android?

Tags: android, image

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Here smaller image is on the top of larger image. I need the same size pictures but larger image should be on top of smaller image.Actually i want to make a photo frame app.The larger image is my photo frame. smaller image is my photo on which photo frame should appear.But in my app, photo is appearing on the photo frame.

i need exactly reverse. Please help me.

Comment: Use a LayerList. Put in your bitmaps in the correct order: 1st = the smaller one, 2nd = the frame.

Comment: I dont know how to use it.If u dont mind,can u pls send me sample code for the above two images pls.

Answer (score 2):

To use a LayerList:

Make 3 files: the LayerList contains the frame and the photo in the correct order: 1 - photo, 2 - frame.

**res/drawable/photoframe.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pf_photo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pf_frame" />
</layer-list>
```

The photo:

**res/drawable/pf_photo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/photo"
    android:dither="true"
    android:antialias="true"
/>
```

The frame:

**res/drawable/pf_frame.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/frame"
    android:dither="true"
    android:antialias="true"
/>
```

Finally, use the LayerList as the background for your RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/photoframe"
>
</RelativeLayout>
```

See how it's simplified, now.

Any frame with a transparent hole will do the trick (nice idea here, would be to use a 9 patch, in order to save space)

So, if you decide to use a 9 patch for the frame,

**res/drawable/photoframe.xml** would become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/frame"
    android:dither="true"
    android:antialias="true"
/>
```

I achived this result:

[image]

by using this 9 patch in the res/drawable folder

**frame.9.png**:

[image]

and this photo in the res/drawable/xxhdpi folder

**photo.jpg**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" 
  android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code provided by Noise Generator ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662631/5003906) works fine. But the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nine-patch
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:src="@drawable/frame"
android:dither="true"
android:antialias="true" />
```

Should be put in pf_frame.xml file.

PS : Sorry writing it as another answer because I don't have enough reputation to write comment.